# Apache commons FPTSClient explicit transfer file is incomplete

Tags: java, ftp-client

Iam currently struggling a little bit with the FTPSClient from Apache Commons. See code down below. I try to write a file to FTP Server (vsftpd) when using FTPClient things are working perfectly fine. When using my code snippet I will always get a 451 Error, when debugging and waiting after Util.copyStream() returned everything works fine or settings a Thread.sleep(100). This also does not happen when I do not set the ftpsClient.execProt("P). Does anyone know by what this could be caused.

```
final FTPSClient client;
        client = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);

        client.setUseClientMode(true);
        client.setDefaultPort(21);

        // connect
        try {
            client.connect("serverAddress", 21);
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        // setup any after connected
        client.setSoTimeout(300);
        client.setListHiddenFiles(true);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        FTPClientConfig ftpConfig;
        try {
            ftpConfig = new FTPClientConfig(client.getSystemType());
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ftpConfig = new FTPClientConfig();
        }
        client.configure(ftpConfig);

        final FTPSClient ftpsClient = client;
        // remove data buffer limit
        ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);
        // set data channel encrypted
        ftpsClient.execPROT("P");

        client.login("user", "password");
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())) {
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed: " + client.getReplyString().trim());
        }

        // postconfigure connection
        if (!client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE) || !client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to correctly configure client: " + client.getReplyString().trim());
        }

        InputStream input;
        OutputStream output;
        input = new FileInputStream(pathToLocalFile);
        output = client.storeFileStream("foobar.txt");
        final var number = Util.copyStream(input, output);
        System.out.println(number);
        input.close();
        // Thread.sleep(100);
        output.close();
        // Must call completePendingCommand() to finish command.
        if (!client.completePendingCommand()) {
             client.logout();
             client.disconnect();
            System.err.println("File transfer failed.");
        }
```

Comment: Do you have port 990 setup (implicit ftp)? Port 21 is usually just plain FTP

Comment: Implicit mode works fine, but not explicit. I tested it with FileZilla and things are working just fine

Comment: The server you connect to has to be setup for explicit.  Here's how to setup FileZilla for explicit ftps https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTPS_using_Explicit_TLS_howto_(Server)

Answer (score 0):

This library has been around for a long time, and things change a bit under the hood.  Try:

```
    input = new FileInputStream(pathToLocalFile);
    boolean result = client.storeFile("foobar.txt", input);
    if (result) {
           System.out.println("\tFile Transfer Completed Successfully");
    }
```

I have noticed that every once in a while when transferring files to a mainframe, it won't complete.  I think it has something to do with the file length, but I've never been able to track it down.  I also don't use the stream_transfer_mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this does not work for me.